# What are historical entries?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

In Hyrule Warriors, as I beat Legend Mode levels, I keep unlocking "historical entries" for various friendly and enemy characters.

Where can I find these entries? They don't seem to be in the Gallery or Settings, which are the only places I can think to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weirdly enough, they're under Tutorials, in the before-starting menu in any stage. Scroll down to the bottom of the list and you'll see entries with the names of various characters.

Comment: what a random place to put them!